# Another site within WordPress page, disabling 404 error for pages that exist but outside of WP system

Tags: php, 404-error

### TLDR;

**Is there a way to disable WordPress's 404 feature for certain pages?**

On one domain, I am running a WordPress site and, under the same domain, I am also trying to run another site parallel to this. (*mysite.com* and *mysite.com/platform*. The reason for this is that the main site (in WP) needs to be updated by the marketers whereas the second site is more complex and is built within another PHP framework.

I have the site online, however, when I try to access mysite.com/platform, it redirects to my 404 page, stating correctly that this page is not found within the WordPress infrastructure.

Is it possible for WordPress to ignore the redirect for this one page?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want to ignore the directory from the WordPress `.htaccess` or `nginx.conf` file. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322559/htaccess-wordpress-exclude-folder-from-rewriterule

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'm using nginx. So, I think I'll have to add an exception to the nginx.conf file as you mention. I'll let you know how it goes :)